# mysql 5.6.35 ST_Contains return null

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  ST_Contains (
    GEOMFROMTEXT(
      'POLYGON(18.4560233 73.8691627, 18.456333 73.869013, 18.456363 73.869404, 18.456200, 73.869383,18.4560233 73.8691627)'
    ),
    GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(18.456266, 73.869210)')
  ) 
FROM
  DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
    ST_CONTAINS
        ( 
             GEOMFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON((18.4560233 73.8691627, 18.456333 73.869013, 18.456363 73.869404, 18.456200 73.869383,18.4560233 73.8691627))' ),
      GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(18.456266 73.869210)') )

FROM DUAL